# Do big classes reduce performance?

Tags: apex, performance, wrapper-class

I have a big (right now it's 1,4k lines) 'toolbox' class. I have a lot of static methods and wrappers there which are used in various number of services or manager/handler classes.
Does anyone notice some performance issues because of a big classes?

Comment: I have a 21,000 line Apex Class that works just as well as a 200 line Apex Class

Answer (score 2):

1400 lines isn't outlandishly big. But if it contains a variety of unrelated methods you might well decide to split it up into separate classes to make your code read better e.g. put all string related methods in a `Strings` class and all List related methods in a `Lists` class.

There are two phases in Salesforce code execution: first compiling and caching classes (or finding the class byte code in the cache if its already there), then second executing the code.

You could speculate on how one big class versus multiple smaller classes would affect the first phase, but given the variety of code bases Salesforce executes, I imagine that performance is well tuned for both cases.

But in the second phase of code execution, it makes sense to be careful that your class/classes do not do unnecessary work when just one static method is called. Here is a somewhat contrived example of what not to do. This code would run - because it is using a static intializer - when any method of the class is called:

```
public class Utils {

    private static Map<String, String> fieldsMap = new Map<String, String>();
    static {
        Map<String, SObjectField> allPlannedTaskFields = DescribeSObjectResultCache.get(PlannedTask__c.SObjectType).fields.getMap();
        Map<String, SObjectField> allTaskFields = DescribeSObjectResultCache.get(Task.SObjectType).fields.getMap();
        for (String plannedTaskField : allPlannedTaskFields.keySet()) {
            if (plannedTaskField.contains('task') && !plannedTaskField.contains('actualtask')) {
                String expectedTaskField = removePrefixAndPostfix(plannedTaskField);
                if (allTaskFields.keySet().contains(expectedTaskField)) {                        
                    fieldsMap.put(plannedTaskField, expectedTaskField);
                } else if (allTaskFields.keySet().contains(expectedTaskField + '__c')){
                    fieldsMap.put(plannedTaskField, expectedTaskField + '__c');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Various static methods

}
```

and as it is probably only relevant to one of the methods and not most of the others that would be a waste.

Comment: THere is no static initialization. There is nothing more than just a logic in a method which is called. This class has methods which retrieve sObjects and methods which wrap these sObjects for REST services. In REST methods I call first type of method and then second. Usually, a few REST methods area called one by one from applications.

Comment: @Chiz Then no need to change because of performance, and if all the methods are related no need to change to improve the [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) either.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is No.
Having Lengthy code in classes is concern about the storage that's it.

If we talk about performance its only related to execution time of each instruction.

Here are some best practice tips for performance.

1)Use Configuration instead of Code, if at all possible.

2)Use Maps instead of Loops, if at all possible.

3)Query before Branches, if at all possible.

4)Query only fields you need.

5)Never query inside a loop.

Try to Reuse the code that will make your class look shorter. This does not affect on performance at all but usually a best practice. for example if we need code modification. How Painful it will be to modify everywhere.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I remember that when Salesforce forced Test Methods to be in Test Classes (api version 28), one of the reasons was related to the Cached size of the Class. You can find more details in this [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/04/apex-test-code-segregation.html)

So it looks like there's some performance impact but only if the cached code is not related with your context. It occupies cache space, which could be used from other parts of the code. Otherwise if most of the code is used, it has to be loaded anyway either in one or in more files.

Comment: I think they did that to force developers to reduce code in each file. I have a few test classes with 1k lines. In addition to this, I have a test utils class which creates test data, which is 1k lines itself.